# Excel Pastespecial VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to copy the contents of a certain workbook to another. However, I indent to keep the source formatting. However, my code produces application/object not defined errors. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D349").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A2")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D349").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing on the clipboard when you specify a destination, so you have to separate the steps:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D349").Copy 
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D349").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```